# images shown in .html but not in pdf

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, nreco

I have a .html file under Content/Templates which has some images as background:

```
.page1 {
        background-image: url('../../images/productdocuments/image1.jpg'); 
        background-size cover;
    }
```

and images inside:

```
<div class="image-container">
            <img class="image" id="mainImage" src="@url" style="width: 124%; height: 81%; margin-left: 4cm;">
        </div>
```

All images are visible in the .html preview.
I am generating a pdf using the template and NReco.PdfGenerator

...

```
 var PdfFile = Tools.ConvertfromHtmltoPdf(Tools.CreatePdf(cPdf));
```

...

```
 public static byte[] ConvertfromHtmltoPdf(string HtmlContent)
            {
    
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HtmlContent))
                    return null;
                var converter = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter();
                return converter.GeneratePdf(HtmlContent);
            }
```

And CreatePdf is:

```
public static string CreatePdf(CPdf cPdf)
        {
            if (cPdf != null)
            {
                string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"\Content\Templates\PTemplate.html");
                if (File.Exists(path))
                {
                    string htmltemplate = File.ReadAllText(path), detail = "";     
                    htmltemplate = htmltemplate.Replace("@categoryurl", cPdf.Picture);
                    return htmltemplate;
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
```

I see `cPdf.Picture` is a URL but why any of these images are not shown on the pdf file?

Comment: Does you 3rd party Generator does logging so you have an idea why it fails? I can just assume that you need to tell it to wait until images are loaded for the html (getting the images in a html is typically an "eventual" thing) or it has problems with the relative pathes in your html that he does not find the images. Either way ideally a log output should tell you that.

Comment: The FAQ item 2 at https://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx says that relative paths are not supported with `GeneratePdf`. Absolute paths must be used (try `Path.GetFullPath(cPdf.Picture)`) or alternatively `GeneratePdfFromFile` with a temporary html file because the replace function will not fix the paths in the CSS file anyway.

Comment: I have added those images to a server and used the URLs of it, now they are shown except cPdf.Picture. cPdf.Picture cannot be accessed through local host, I guess this is the problem. I will check when I upload the project on the server. @delightfulmemento

Comment: there is no log output but now I am almost sure that it cannot find the images. @Ralf

Comment: @wittream Yes, you should make the `cPdf.Picture` also accessible by URL, or local **absolute** path, depending on where the files are the `MapPath` method you are already using may work for that too. (Logging can be enabled by setting `converter.Quiet = false` but it may need custom event handling, not sure.)

Comment: @delightfulmemento MapPath worked thank you!